# Protractor quotes issue

Tags: javascript, regex, protractor

i have a question about a problem i am having with quotes inside protractor.

Here is my code :

```
browser.executeScript('var str = window.document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerText;var patt = new RegExp("16.5");console.log(patt);var res = patt.test(str);console.log(res);if(res){window.location="http://www.mysite.nl/info/"}');
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe('http://www.mysite.nl/info/');
```

this works just fine ,but now i want the RegEXP("16.5") to check if "status": "ok" is inside the string .

what i want is : RegEXP(" "status": "ok" ") ,but ofcourse this won't work and i can't use the single quotes because of the single quotes from browser.executeScript .

Does somebody know how i can still get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a regex literal instead:

```
var patt = /"status": "ok"/;
```

although it's unclear why you'd use a regex at all since the string is fixed.

Also, be aware that the regex `16.5` also matches `1645` or `16X5`. The dot has special meaning in a regex...